# Question marks in ASP pages

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6, iis-7.5

I am currently migrating a website from IIS6 to IIS7.5. I have a classic ASP file encoded in ANSI (according to Notepad++) which connects to a database and retrieves data with characters outside the ANSI range (Gaelic characters) and displays them on the page. When I then view the page in my browser, the Gaelic characters are displayed as question marks. I can change the encoding of the ASP file to UTF-8 and the Gaelic characters are displayed fine.

The problem is I have tens of thousands of ASP pages which I would need to convert to UTF-8 which, at the moment, isn't an option to apply the conversion.

1. Is there any way I can configure my web server (IIS7.5) to read the ASP file as UTF-8?
2. Is there an alternative solution to converting all the pages to UTF-8?

These pages work fine on IIS6 for some reason.

Comment: Do they share the same layout?

Comment: The file running on IIS7 is a copy of the one running on IIS6. They are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just stumbled upon the answer.

1. Open IIS manager
2. Select either the server or website node
3. Make sure you are in Features View
4. Open the ASP settings
5. There should be a setting called `Code Page`. Set this to the value `65001`
6. Click `Apply` in the actions pane on the right

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, too - the Hebrew being output by my MySQL database was rendering in the browser as ??????????, for example. (I created a classic ASP app, the output of which is in Hebrew.)

I tried everything and NOTHING worked.

Then I realized I was using the wrong (ANSI) ODBC connector.  You have to use the **Unicode** one, at least if your data is coming from a MySQL database.

So, your connection string would contain this:
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};

and not this:
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};

Now, it displays perfectly.  I sincerely hope this helps some folks!